# Estimate size of smallest solution to linear program

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra

I have a linear program: a system of linear inequalities of the form

$$Ax \le b, \qquad x \ge 0.$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix.

I am looking for an upper-bound on the size of the smallest solution to this system of inequalities.  In other words, I'd like to find a constant $c$ where I can make some statement like

"If this system has any solution, then it has a solution $x$ such that $||x|| \le c$."

where $c$ depends somehow on $A,B$, and where you can pick any norm of your choice.  Are there any known techniques or results of this form?

---

In my specific application, I happen to know that every entry in $A$ is $-1$, $0$, or $+1$.  Intuitively, it seems like the bad case that can force $c$ to be big is where I have inequalities that correspond to hyperplanes that have a small angle between them; however, if the entries of $A$ are all in $\{-1,0,+1\}$, it seems like that bad case can't happen, which is why it seems like there might be some hope for some kind of nice result along these lines.  (For instance, if taking $c=\sum_i b_i$ and using the $L_{\infty}$ norm let me make such a statement, that would be the kind of result I would find useful.)  Is anything along these lines known?

Comment: Yup.  That seems useful.  Any kind of result for the max-norm would be great: even an asymptotic or not-tight upper bound...

Comment: @LeonMeier, thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately the "big M" method doesn't help.  It's basically running the simplex algorithm.  In other words, it is a non-trivial algorithm.  I'm not looking for an algorithm (otherwise I could just run a LP algorithm to minimize $\|x\|_\infty$ subject to $Ax\le b$, $x \ge 0$).  Rather, I'm looking for a bound that can be computed simply.  For instance, see the last paragraph of my question: if we know that each entry $A_{ij}$ is either $-1$, $0$, or $+1$, can we upper-bound $c$ (say as a function of $m,n$)?  "Big M" doesn't seem to help with that.

Comment: OK.  Do you have a pointer?  I haven't been able to find anything like that.  Alternatively, do you have any suggestions for how I can improve my question?